# How can I solve the"FILTER has mismatched range sizes" error in the formula below

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, filtering

I get the filter has mismatched range error when I insert this: `Data!N3:N  <> "", "No Market")`

Formula in Google Sheets

`=FILTER(Data!B3:N,`
`Data!C3:C>=B1,`
`Data!C3:C<=D1,`
`Data!N3:N  <> "", "No Market")`

I'm trying to replace the blank values in Column N with the text "No Market"

Sample Table

| Column B | Column N |
| --- | --- |
| 03/07/2021 | New York |
| 03/07/2021 |  |
| 03/07/2021 | Seattle |
| 04/04/2021 |  |
| 04/04/2021 | Boston |

This formula also worked, but it excludes the blank values and I would like to include them.
`=FILTER(Data!B3:N,`
`Data!C3:C>=B1,`
`Data!C3:C<=D1,`
`Data!N3:N <> "")`

| Column B | Column N |
| --- | --- |
| 03/07/2021 | New York |
| 03/07/2021 | Seattle |
| 04/04/2021 | Boston |

Expected Results:replaces blank values with "No Market"

| Column B | Column N |
| --- | --- |
| 03/07/2021 | New York |
| 03/07/2021 | No Market |
| 03/07/2021 | Seattle |
| 04/04/2021 | No Market |
| 04/04/2021 | Boston |

I appreciate your help, thanks in advance!

Comment: You are only showing Col B and Col N. Are those the only two columns you want? Or do you actually need every column beginning with Col B and ending with Col N (i.e. 13 columns in all)?

Comment: Yes, I'm using all 13.

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula-

```
=ArrayFormula({A2:A6,IF(B2:B6="","No Market",B2:B6)})
```

[image]

Comment: Dada you are super!

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked, I just need to add the first part of the formula: Data!C3:C>=B1, Data!C3:C<=D1 as if then statement to work in the arrayformula, but I think I can figure it out now based off of your example.

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to write full formulas without access to any actual data, but this *should* work for you:

`=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(FILTER({Data!B3:M, IF(Data!N3:N="", "No Market", Data!N3:N)}, Data!C3:C<>"", Data!C3:C>=B1, Data!C3:C<=D1)))`

If it does not work as expected, consider sharing a link to the spreadsheet.

Comment: it's private so I can't share it, but thank you.

Comment: Did the formula work?